# Can I make a closed-source game if part of it utilizes a EUPL-licenced code?

Tags: derivative-works, proprietary-code, eupl

I want to make an app game in which I make use of a code that is licensed under the EUPL. The code will probably make up about 10 to 20 percent of the game's entire code (the rest will be original work). Will I be required to make the whole game open-sourced if I use that EUPL code? Are there any factors that would limit my ownership rights?

Answer (score 2):

If your game is a derivative work (which it likely is unless you're very sure it isn't) of the EUPL software it will also have to be released under the EUPL. See section 5 in the [license text](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/eupl1.1.-licence-en_0.pdf):

> Copyleft clause: If the Licensee distributes and/or communicates copies of the Original Works or Derivative Works based upon the Original Work, this Distribution and/or Communication will be done under the terms of this Licence or of a later version of this Licence unless the Original Work is expressly distributed only under this version of the Licence. The Licensee (becoming Licensor) cannot offer or impose any additional terms or conditions on the Work or Derivative Work that alter or restrict the terms of the Licence.